# Vue: Twitch player events won't fire with VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, twitch

I'm working with the Twitch API, specifically embeds. I want to embed a player so I have this:

```js
var options = {
  width: 400,
  height: 300,
  channel: "twitchpresents"
};
var player = new Twitch.Player("SamplePlayerDivID", options);

const v = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  methods: {
    init: function() {
      player.addEventListener(Twitch.Player.READY, () => {
        alert("Player is ready!!");
      });
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.init();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://player.twitch.tv/js/embed/v1.js"></script>

   <!-- <div id="SamplePlayerDivID"></div> ALERT() ONLY FIRES IF HERE -->
<div id="app">
  <div id="SamplePlayerDivID"></div>
</div>
```

The embed works, it plays, (though probably not in the snippet) but the problem is, for some reason if I keep the twitch `<div id="SamplePlayerDivID"></div>` inside of `#app`, the events never fire. In fact, f I bind the player to the `window`, none of the normal player methods work either such as `player.getChannel()`.

Only when I take it out of the vue instance does it work... How can I make the events fire whilst keeping it inside `#app` (without components) and why does this even happen in the first place?

I tried using `v-pre` on the player div to try ignore it so that events fire as normal but that doesn't work.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MPErqY?editors=1010

Comment: You're probably better off making the twitch player into a component. I'm tired and it's early, [so here's your codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZqXvNQ?editors=1010)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I appreciate that. But I can't use a component within my project, it's going to complicate things.

Comment: Okay. Then move the `var player = new Twitch.Player("SamplePlayerDivID", options);
` inside of the `init()` function.

Comment: Will `player` be globally accessible to all methods in the vue instance if I do that?

Comment: Okay, your method works and it is accessible. Whilst you've solved my issue, I wish to have an understanding as to why the way I have it at the moment doesn't work.

Comment: Because `VueJS` replaces the contents with a Virtual DOM of its own when you instantiate it, so you lose reference to it temporarily. Your code was executing on page load and then would be unbound because of this. Moving it inside of the `init` function makes it so that the `mounted` lifecycle method handles the execution of the code, so the virtual DOM is available at that point.

Comment: Understood, great. Please formulate your comments into an answer so I may accept it and mark this as solved.

Comment: @AshleyBrown did you find the solution?

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim Read the above comments.

Comment: yes i seen the latest comment of Ohgodwhy but i can't see the difference between what he said and your question

Comment: ...should there be a difference? I'm not quite sure what you mean? It doesn't seem coherent. Either way, clearly by me stating `"Whilst you've solved my issue"` and `"mark this as solved"` should make it clear that the problem has been solved.